# Why is the Projection (cB) of Vector A on B perpendicular to Vector A - cB?

Tags: linear-algebra

The following excerpt can be found in Serge Lang's Introduction to Linear Algebra. I am trying to understand mathematically why the vector $\mathbf{A}- c\mathbf{B}$ is perpendicular to the vector $c\mathbf{B}$. I suppose there would be a simple mathematical explanation behind this, but I haven't been able to find any. I have tried taking the dot product of $\mathbf{A} - c\mathbf{B}$ and $c\mathbf{B}$ to equal $0$, but I cannot find any proof as to why this dot product would have to equal $0$.

[image]

Comment: It won't be true for an arbitrary value of $c$ .Presumably Lang goes on to calculate what value of $c$ makes it true?

Comment: Can you provide the complete question or the page no. of your context from the book which you have taken.

Comment: From the part of the text you show, it seems like he is *defining* the projection to be the unique vector $P$ which is parallel to $B$ and such that $A-P$ is perpendicular to $B$. At least secretly.

Comment: @Doubtnut The diagram was on page 23 of his second edition.

Comment: I've edited the question by posting image of the complete section which might be helpful for other users to understand the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bungo has mentioned, it is not true for an arbitrary value $c\in\textbf{F}$. It just states the projection of $A$ lies in the direction $B$. More precisely, in order to find $c$, it has to satisfy the following relation:
\begin{align*}
\langle A-cB,cB\rangle = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow \langle A,cB\rangle - \langle cB,cB\rangle = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \overline{c}\langle A,B\rangle - c\overline{c}\langle B,B\rangle = 0
\end{align*}

If $B\neq 0$ and $c\neq 0$, it results that
\begin{align*}
\langle A,B\rangle - c\langle B,B\rangle = 0 \Longleftrightarrow c = \frac{\langle A,B\rangle}{\langle B,B\rangle}
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully it helps.